# How to prevent Jenkins Pipeline agent from taking one slot from the main machine's slots

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following Jenkins Pipelines script:

```
pipeline{

agent any

stages {

    stage('First Step'){
        agent { label 'TheSecondAgent'}
            steps {
                ... Do stuff
            }  
        }
    }
    
    stage('Second Step'){
        agent { label 'TheSecondAgent'}
            steps {
                ... Do even more stuff
            }  
        }
    }
    
    ... Bunch more steps here
    
    stage('Archive Artifacts'){
            agent { 
            node { label 'TheSecondAgent'
                   customWorkspace 'another/path/where/artifacts/are'
               }
        }
            steps {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/logs/*.xml, **/logs/*.json, **/logs/*.log', followSymlinks: false
        
        }
    }
}

post {
    always{
        node('TheSecondAgent'){
            dir('path/to/logs'){
                xunit(tools: [ xUnitDotNet(pattern: '**/logs/*-jenkinsLogs.xml') ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And as we can see, there is another agent set for every step in this pipeline. However, when I run this job, I can still see, that this takes one slot from the main Jenkin's slots as well as from the agent's slots.

Previously this was fixed by setting the agent at the top of this pipeline to none, but that prevents me from using Artifacts and post builds, so it has to be as "any".... I think.

Is there a way to "block" or somehow "force" this script to run only in the agent computer, in this case agent named: TheSecondAgent?

Comment: Why not set 'TheSecondAgent' at the pipeline level if you need it for each stage?

Comment: @Iterokun As mentioned in the post, Artifactoring and Post steps did not work, if the so called "Top-level" agent was anything but "any". And it also causes the issue, where the job just never starts... It will stay in this: Waiting for next available executor on ‘TheOtherAgent’ step forever.

Comment: Are you saying that if you get the example Hello World pipeline and change the top level agent from `any` to `{ label 'TheSecondAgent' }` the job never starts? I think you need to solve that before you can move on to `post` section not working.

Comment: I am guessing here, but if you have problems with archiving this is related to the fact you are trying to archive things from beyond your workspace. This is not supported in [archiveArtifacts step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts). You should `mv` or `rsync` stuff to your workspace before archiving.